# Docker with .NetCore, should I use the SDK or Runtime image for micro-services?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm pretty new to docker and I was wondering.

When you are working with many micro-services (50+). Is it still relevant to use the runtime image versus the SDK image?

In order to use the runtime image, I need to do a self-contained publish, that is around 100MO bigger.

With 50 micro-services, it's 5GO of data, to have self-contained app.

Is it worth it to take the Runtime image in this case?

Comment: Why are you doing a self contained publish if you're using a runtime image? My understanding is that self contained has *everything* the app needs to run, including the framework. But since the runtime image provides the framework, I don't know why you'd need to do self contained.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The runtime image contains the *runtime*, so you don't need to publish self-contained. The SDK is only required if you need to *build*. The runtime has everything necessary to, you know, run. If you're publishing self-contained, you'd only need the OS, so your base image would just be alpine or something, not ASP.NET Core at all (because ASP.NET Core would be *contained* in the app).

Then, Docker has staged builds. As such, the typical way to do this is to build and publish all in the image, just in different stages. The final image is based on the last stage, so that is where you'd reference the runtime image. For example:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

Each `FROM` line indicates a new stage. The only thing that survives is the final stage, where all that's being done is the published files are copied in and the app is run, giving you an optimally sized image. However, using the staged build, all the logic necessary to build and publish your app is contained in the image.

Comment: Thanks to your anwser I figure out where I was wrong.

I was using the image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/**runtime**, this image doesn't contain Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

This lead to the error : "The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.6' was not found." when I was running the image.

If someone have the same issue: Don't use the image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime,  but use mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet instead.